# Laravel socialite besides normal registration - is password nullable() the only way?

Tags: laravel

Are there any security concerns with setting the Password field to nullable? If so, what are they?

Comment: if the password is nullable, an empty password would be allowed, and thats a security risk. Why would that field be nullable?

Comment: @GertB. Hi Gert! Because with a socialte auth, no password is required.

Comment: You could generate random password for these users. Or you could add nullable pwd in migration, but in this case you need to know if user comes from socialite or basic registration. For example, if pwd is empty then person cannot login.

Comment: There is no real security concern to set a nullable password as long as you don't allow anyone to login without providing a password or using a social authentication e.g. if someone provides a username and no password for an account where they previously used a social log in make absolutely sure you don't just let them log in

Comment: Agreed to the above; for Socialite, or SSO (Single-Sign On), etc., you generally do not store a password in the Database, as it is handled _elsewhere_. Laravel's default authentication requires both an Email (or Username) and Password, but you _can_ login a User without a Password (`auth()->login(User::first())`, etc.). As long as you don't program the ability for a non-socialite User to login without a Password, you're fine, and this is not a security risk.